# List item permissions

Tags: list, permissions, list-item

I would like to create a list of ideas for employees to add.
I want to have another column where only me can Approve/Decline ideas..

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08

Basically content approval let's you keep a buffer state for all items, between when they are added by users and when they are actually visible to everyone else. Any item will be visible to other users only once it has been approved by any one of the user with approve permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do an Approval OOB workflow. Or, more simply, add a Approve/Decline field, create a permissions group for users with only Add permissions and give yourself Contribute or Full Control so that only you can edit the list items.

Answer (score -1):

When talking about permissions and approval, we got many options:

1 - Classical "Item requires approval".
Can be achieved through basic list permissions setup.

2 - Customizing forms (via Sharepoint designer or visual studio custom webparts) to show the "approval" column only to some specific group of users.

3 - Customizing forms with Infopath, setting up "audience" to show the approval field only to specific group.

It would also be dependant on your requirements... users can edit the ideas? They can see the refused ideas? Your requirements will naturally take you to the best option. Good luck!